# Solving interpolation problem with B-splines

Tags: polynomials, numerical-methods, interpolation, spline

I have a sequence of $N$ equispaced knots defined in the interval $[t_0,t_f]$ and a number of values, $x(t_i), i=1...N+1$, that requires **perfect** matching at these knots. The resulting interpolating function has to assure $C^2$ continuity for $[t_0,t_f]$.

I have solved the above problem using piecewise splines at each interval as $x(t)=\sum^{m}_{j=0}\alpha_jt^j, \> \> t \in [(i-1),i](t_f-t_0)/N$ and considering null first derivatives at $t_0$ and $t_f$ to close the system (values at knots+$C^2$ continuity) considering $m=3$.

I have been looking at B-splines and they have interesting properties since they match $C^2$ continuity intrinsecally (if I am not wrong). However I do not know if they assure perfect interpolation for my values at the knots. Can my problem be solved with B-splines formulation? How?

Comment: Are your knots equally spaced?

Comment: "Natural cubic spline" should be exactly what you need.

Comment: @user14717, yes, my knots are equally spaced. Ok, fang, I will take a look at these

Comment: @Julio: A C^2 interpolator for equally spaced knots if given here: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/math/doc/html/math_toolkit/cubic_b.html

Comment: The linked interpolator does indeed obey the interpolation condition.

Comment: Thx @user14717. More interested in the reference than in the interpolator (I am making my own interpolation).